# Understanding TCP session captured in Wireshark

Tags: tcp, wireshark

I'm new to Wireshark and are wondering about a few thing...

The linked figure shows the TCP session captured in Wireshark

[image: Screenshot of the TCP session captured in Wireshark]

My questions are:

1. How large is the window size in bytes for the given segment?
2. What type of window is this?
3. Which phase of a TCP connection does the selected segment belong to?
4. How many bytes of payload are transferred in the given segment?
5. Who sends the given TCP segment?
6. How many bytes of payload from the application layer has been sent and received up until and including segment number 1446?
7. Which application layer protocol is being used here?
8. What type of connection does the application layer protocol use?
9. How can user state be handled for a HTTP connection, so that the web server remembers the settings from the previous time the user visited the web site?
10. Does the selected HTTP message transfer a user state indicator?

Comment: This seems to be a copy-paste from an homework.

Comment: That is correct